# Scrape only HTML+Microdata with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, microdata

**Problem**

I need to scrape HTML pages and extract only the HTML that has Microdata in it.

**Example**

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <span>SOMETHING ELSE</span>
  <script>SOMETHING</script>
  <h1 itemprop="name"&g;Avatar</h1>
  <div itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  Director: <span itemprop="name">James Cameron</span> (born <span itemprop="birthDate">August 16, 1954)</span>
  <img url="DOESNT MATTER" />
  </div>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>

<div>SOMETHING ELSE</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="brand">ACME</span>
  <span itemprop="name">Executive Anvil</span>

  <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span>SOMETHING ELSE</span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    $<span itemprop="price">119.99</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Goal: only the HTML with Microdata**

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <div itemprop="director" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  Director: <span itemprop="name">James Cameron</span> (born <span itemprop="birthDate">August 16, 1954)</span>
  </div>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="brand">ACME</span>
  <span itemprop="name">Executive Anvil</span>
  <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    $<span itemprop="price">119.99</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Attempt**

I tried to use:

```ruby
doc.css("*[itemtype]").each do |container|
  puts container.to_html
end
```

But that doesn't work because it iterates each `itemtype` and outputs all their childen `itemtype` and after that it iterates again their children so it duplicate things, i.e., MOVIE+PERSON > PERSON > PRODUCT+OFFER > OFFER.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don’t just use a Microdata parser to extract the structured data (instead of the markup)?

Comment: We want to cache the microdata HTML markup and provide that in another version of our pages.